# prove that $f’(x)e^{\lambda x}$ is increasing if and only if $f’(x)+\lambda f(x)$ is increasing. Where $f\in C^1(0,\infty)$.

Tags: derivatives, inequality, monotone-functions

prove that $f’(x)e^{\lambda x}$ is increasing if and only if $f’(x)+\lambda f(x)$ is increasing. Where $f\in C^1(0,\infty)$, and $\lambda$ is a real number.

I have tried to prove it by taking $0<x_1<x_2$ to make difference and to control each other. But it seems not that easy, I also have tried to prove it by contradiction, it failed as I need to find a small interval that $f’$ is monotone. But it isn’t always satisfied.

Can anyone help me to figure it out or just give me some intention? Very appreciate it!

Comment: Not really a step towards a proof, but you get a symmetrical and equivalent statement that $g'(x) - \lambda g(x)$ is increasing if and only if $g'(x)e^{-\lambda x}$ is increasing by letting $g(x) = f(x)e^{\lambda x}$

Comment: Yeah, thx anyway.@NinadMunshi

Answer (score 5):

I have decided to undelete this partial answer (it was a bit incorrect) but I hope the following observations contribute something. We have two statements:

i) $f'(x)e^{\lambda x}$ is increasing

ii) $f'(x) + \lambda f(x)$ is increasing

**Case 1:** $\lambda >0 $ then i) implies ii). Fix $x_0 >0$, consider $x\geq x_0$, we have $ f'(x)e^{\lambda x} \geq f'(x_0)e^{\lambda x_0} $, hence

$$ f(x) - f(x_0) = \int^{x}_{x_0}f'(u)du \geq f'(x_0) \int^{x}_{x_0} e^{\lambda(x_0-u)}du = \frac{f'(x_0)}{\lambda} \left(1-e^{\lambda(x_0-x)} \right), $$

which implies

$$ f'(x) - f'(x_0) + \lambda (f(x) - f(x_0)) \geq f'(x) - f'(x_0)e^{\lambda(x_0-x)} \geq 0 $$

**Case 2:** $\lambda <0$ then ii) implies i). For $x \geq x_0$, we have

$$-f'(x) \leq -f'(x_0) + \int^x_{x_0}\lambda f'(u)du, $$
by Gronwall inequality (requires $\lambda < 0$), it holds that

$$ -f'(x) \leq  -f'(x_0)e^{-\int^x_{x_0} \lambda du} =  -f'(x_0) e^{\lambda(x_0-x)} \implies  f'(x)e^{\lambda x} \geq f'(x_0)e^{\lambda x_0}. $$

The cases left are

1. $\lambda <0 $, i) $\implies$ ii)
2. $\lambda >0 $, ii) $\implies$ i)

Comment: I think you were very close (+1)!

Comment: Good observations,+1

Answer (score 5):

(This is highly inspired by [LNT's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4816265/42969).)

**Part 1:** If $F(x) = f'(x)e^{\lambda x}$ is increasing then $G(x) = f'(x) + \lambda f(x)$ is also increasing.

*Proof:* Assume that $F$ is increasing and let $0 < a < b$. Then
$$
 f(b)-f(a)  = \int_a^b f'(x) \, dx 
= \int_a^b  F(x) e^{-\lambda x} \, dx 
= F(c) \int_a^b   e^{-\lambda x} \, dx
$$
for some $c \in (a, b)$, using the general form of the [first mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals). It follows that
$$
\lambda( f(b)-f(a)) = F(c) \lambda \int_a^b   e^{-\lambda x} \, dx
= \underbrace{F(c)}_{\ge F(a)} e^{-\lambda a} -  \underbrace{F(c)}_{\le F(b)} e^{-\lambda b} \\
\ge F(a) e^{-\lambda a} -  F(b) e^{-\lambda b} = f'(a) - f'(b)
$$
and therefore
$$
G(b) - G(a) = f'(b)-f'(a) + \lambda( f(b)-f(a)) \ge 0 \, ,
$$
i.e. $G$ is increasing.

**Part 2:** If $G(x) = f'(x) + \lambda f(x)$ is increasing then $F(x) = f'(x)e^{\lambda x}$  is also increasing.

*Proof:* This can be concluded from part 1. Assume that $G$ is increasing and define the function $g\in C^1(0,\infty)$ as $g(x) = f(x)e^{\lambda x}$. Then
$$
 g'(x)e^{-\lambda x} =  f'(x) + \lambda f(x) = G(x)
$$
is increasing. We can apply part 1 to $g$ and $-\lambda$ and it follows that
$$
 g'(x) - \lambda g(x) = f'(x) e^{\lambda x} = F(x)
$$
is also increasing.

*Remark:* “Increasing” here means “weakly increasing“ or “nondecreasing.” But the same proof works for strict monotony, i.e. we also have the equivalence

> $f'(x)e^{\lambda x}$ is stricly increasing if and only if $ f'(x) + \lambda f(x)$ is stricly increasing.

Comment: Thanks for giving me credits. Indeed, I tried sth like you did in part 1 but I didn't remember that general MVT so I gave it no more thoughts :). The proof seems correct to me btw.

Comment: @LNT: In the first version of my answer (you can see it in the edit history) I considered the cases $\lambda \ge 0$ and $\lambda < 0$ separately, doing a calculation very similar to yours.  That's why I said “you were very close”: Your argument  works for $\lambda < 0$ as well, only that $f'(x)e^{\lambda x}$ has to be its value at the *upper* bound of the integral. – Later I discovered that using the MVT makes the proof simpler.

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks for the complete proof and that "MVT" observation

Comment: Very nice proof! +1

Comment: thx so nice proof！

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)=f'(x)+\lambda f(x)$

Assume $p(x)$ be non-monotonic function

$p'(x)=f''(x)+\lambda f'(x)<0$ for some $x=x_°\in \mathbb{R}$

Hence $$r(x)=e^{\lambda x}p'(x)=e^{\lambda x}f''(x)+e^{\lambda x}\lambda f'(x)<0$$ for some $x=x_°\in \mathbb{R}$

Now consider $q(x)=f'(x)e^{\lambda x}$

$$q'(x)=f''(x)e^{\lambda x}+\lambda f'(x)e^{\lambda x}$$

Now $q'(x)=r(x)<0$ for some $x=x_°\in \mathbb{R}$

It means $q(x)$ is non-monotone if $p(x)$ is non-monotone,Similarly,It can be shown $q(x)$ is monotone if $p(x)$ is monotone

This proves that $q(x)$ is monotone if and only only if $p(x)$ is monotone

Now consider $q(x)$ to be monotonically increasing,This can be similarly proved to be true if and only if $p(x)$ is monotonically increasing,

Comment: What if the second derivative $f''$ does not exist?

Comment: @MartinR,My bad,I feel naive after this Comment

Comment: I have done it but not sure if it is true.@MartinR   @Dheeraj Gujrathi

Comment: If $f$ is twice differentiable then there is a simple one-line proof: $q'(x)=(f''(x) + \lambda f'(x)) e^{\lambda x}$ and $p'(x) = f''(x) + \lambda f'(x)$ have the same sign. The challenge here is to use only $f\in C^1(0,\infty)$.